# Perl with Moo: How to call superclass's implementation of a method?

Tags: perl, oop, moo

I have a class `X` with a subclass `Y`.  `X` has a method `calculate()` that I'd like to override in `Y` with some additional behaviour, an `if` statement that, if it fails, call `X.calculate()`.  In Python this would be accomplished with:

```
class X(object):
    def calculate(self, my_arg):
        return "Hello!"

class Y(X):
    def calculate(self, my_arg):
        if type(my_arg) is int and my_arg > 5:
            return "Goodbye!"
        return super(Y, self).calculate(my_arg)
```

How can I do this in Perl using the `Moo` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo#INCOMPATIBILITIES-WITH-MOOSE) point out:

> No support for `super`, `override`, `inner`, or `augment` - the author considers augment to be a bad idea, and ***`override` can be translated***:
>
> ```
> around foo => sub {
>   my ($orig, $self) = (shift, shift);
>   ...
>   $self->$orig(@_);
>   ...
> };
> ```
>
> (emphasis mine)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package X;

use Moo;

sub calculate {
    return 'Hello!'
}


package Y;

use Moo;

extends 'X';

around calculate => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;

    if ( $_[0] > 5 ) {
        return $self->$orig(@_);
    }

    return 'Goodbye!';
};

package main;

my $y = Y->new;

print $y->calculate(3), "\n";
print $y->calculate(11), "\n";
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!  The docs are so terrible on this.  I thought I needed to use `before` but even then I couldn't figure out how to do it!  Thanks again for your help.  Perfection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in Perl via the [`SUPER::` pseudo-class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Inheritance), which is part of Perl's method resolution system. You just put it in front of the method-call. It does not work for class methods or function calls.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

package Foo;
use Moo;

sub frobnicate {
    my $self = shift;
    say "foo";
}

package Bar;
use Moo;
extends 'Foo';

sub frobnicate {
    my $self = shift;
    say "bar";
    $self->SUPER::frobnicate;    
}

package main;
Bar->new->frobnicate;
```

You can even use this to call each parent's method if you have multi-level inheritance.

```
package Grandparent;
sub foo { ... }

package Parent;
use parent 'Grandparent';
sub foo { $_[0]->SUPER::foo }

package Child;
use parent 'Parent';
sub foo { $_[0]->SUPER::foo }
```

This will subsequently call `foo` in Child, Parent and Grandparent.

Comment: Re "*Both Moo and Moose support this*", It's part of Perl's method dispatching, so it's always available.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately this didn't work for me and I'm not entirely sure why...